# Adding data to Array inside an object using React Hook

Tags: arrays, reactjs, immutability, react-hooks

I confuse about how adding array data to array list inside an object using setState by hook in React. can someonehelp me about this?
below are my code, everytime i console log it always return empty array.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Main = props => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    noteArray: [],
    noteText: '',
  });


  const addNote = () => {
    if(state.noteText){
      var d = new Date();
      let x = {
        'date': d.getFullYear() + 
        "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1 ) +
        "/" + d.getDate(),
        'note': state.noteText
      }

      setState({...state, noteArray: x});

      console.log(state.noteArray);
    }
  }

   .......................the rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you are doing wrong is that you are overriding your array instead of adding new value to it. You can do this easily using this:-

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Main = props => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    noteArray: [],
    noteText: '',
  });


  const addNote = () => {
    if(state.noteText){
      var d = new Date();
      let x = {
        'date': d.getFullYear() + 
        "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1 ) +
        "/" + d.getDate(),
        'note': state.noteText
      }

      setState({...state, noteArray: [...state.noteArray, x]});

      console.log(state.noteArray);
    }
  }

   .......................the rest of code
}
```

Comment: ur code, get stuck in infinite loop, below is the udpated one

Comment: @ukiyakimura are you trying to reset your array or are you trying to append into it?

Comment: @solanki... Can you please explain how will this go into an infinite loop? Have already tested this locally, works fine

Comment: i'm trying to append it @YashGadle

Comment: how do i force the state to update immediately by using setState?, it still not change the value until the component got re-rendered first. @Yash Gadle

Comment: You can never force a re-render immediately. React does it when it is necessary. Check out this working example for your use case  - https://codesandbox.io/s/52ql2y0jlp?fontsize=14